# wget downloads nofollow link

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, wget

I want to crawl/scrape a wordpress website with wget.
Problem: wget will download documents/links despite them having a `rel=nofollow` attribute. And yes I do allow robots.txt.

Example:

`wget --mirror --page-requisites --adjust-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent --span-hosts --domains=randomascii.wordpress.com,wp.com  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/about/`

Now open the `about` folder and after some seconds you will see dozens of html files that stem from nofollow links: `index.html@share=reddit.html`, `index.html@share=twitter.html`, `index.html@replytocom=74214.html` ...

```
GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on msys.

-cares +digest +gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +metalink +nls
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl

Wgetrc:
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale:
    /usr/share/locale
Compile:
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib -DHAVE_LIBSSL
    -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
Link:
    gcc -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
    -pipe -lmetalink -lexpat -lpcre2-8 -luuid -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lz
    -lpsl -lidn2 -liconv -lunistring -lgpgme -lassuan -lgpg-error
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a -liconv -lintl
    /usr/lib/libunistring.dll.a
```

Comment: This should probably be asked on superuser instead of here.

Comment: I actually thought about this before making this post and there is also a topic about that (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97679/where-are-questions-about-wget-usage-on-topic/97726) but overall, wget questions seem to be asked 4x more on SO nowadays (800:3400), hence I asked here. Probably it's more like a bugreport though... At least if at least someone could confirm that it does not work and the problem is not me. Also happens on Debian, so it's not my wget version.